# Domain issue with the function $\frac{\sqrt{3 - x}}{\sqrt{(x + 1)(x - 1)}}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have been trying to solve this domain and a lot of question come in my mind which is pretty confusing.

I found the following answer on another website:

> Divide the two functions.  $$\frac{\sqrt{3 - x}}{\sqrt{(x + 1)(x - 1)}}$$ The zeros of this function are $x = -1, 1, 3$.  We check $x < -1$, $-1 < x < 1$, $1 < x < 3$, and $x > 3$.  The only ranges that work are $x < -3$ and $1 < x < 3$.  Then we check $x = 3$, $x = -1$, and $x = 1$.  Only $x = 3$ works, so our domain is $x < -1$ and $1 < x \le 3$.

The denominator range is between $-1$ to $1$. Then why we do care about the numerator? $3$ is out of range. If we even use it in the function we will just get $0$ but the function is not undefined. Then why did they include $3$ in the domain of this function?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The screenshot says $3$ is a zero of the function but the way the zeroes are being described, it looks like the function should be $\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)\left(x-1\right)}}$. Is the square root on top cropped out of the screenshot?

Comment: yours is right.

Comment: How should I upload problems then?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Am I correct in assuming that the material in the image is a quote from a book and that the top and bottom paragraphs are your own work?

Comment: NO. it is just a answer from random website. I am just trying to understand this issue that's it. Thanks for the link tho.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ to be in the domain of this function, the terms inside the radicals cannot be negative and the denominator cannot equal zero.

For the numerator, the term inside the radical must be nonnegative:  $3 - x \geq 0 \implies 3 \geq x$.

For the denominator, the term inside the radical must be positive since it cannot equal zero:  $(x + 1)(x - 1) > 0 \implies x > 1$ or $x < -1$.

Observe that $(x + 1)(x - 1) < 0$ in the interval $(-1, 1)$.  For instance, substituting $0$ makes the product $(x + 1)(x - 1) = (0 + 1)(0 - 1) = (1)(-1) = -1$.

Thus, we have $x \leq 3$ and $(x > 1$ or $x < -1)$.  Hence, $(x \leq 3$ and $x > 1) \implies 1 < x \leq 3$, or $(x \leq 3$ and $x < -1) \implies x < -1$. Therefore, the domain of the function is $$\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < -1~\text{or}~1 < x \leq 3\} = (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, 3]$$

Comment: If there is no root in the numerator then would it make a change? Or just because it has root, so that a negative over root makes it undefined?

Comment: If the function were $g(x) = \frac{3 - x}{\sqrt{(x + 1)(x - 1)}}$, then the only restrictions would be that the term inside the radical must be positive.  The term $(x + 1)(x - 1)$ cannot be negative since it is inside a square root, and it cannot be zero since it is in the denominator.  Hence, the domain of the function $g$ would be $(-\infty, - 1) \cup (1, \infty)$.  The function $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3 - x}}{\sqrt{(x + 1)(x - 1)}}$ has the additional restriction that $3 - x \geq 0$ since $3 - x$ is inside a square root.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand that now clearly

Answer (score 0):

In order for both the numerator and the denominator being defined and for the denominator not to be zero, the domain is given by
\begin{align*}
D=&\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 3-x \ge 0, x^2 - 1 > 0\} \\
=& ]-\infty, 3] \cap\left(]-\infty,-1[ \cup ]1, +\infty[\right)\\
=&]-\infty, -1[\cup ]1, 3].
\end{align*}

I think that your confusion comes from a wrong solution to the inequality $x^2-1 >0$.

Comment: Kinda. I was just more confused about the numerator part. why we are counting this, since the domain is negative 1 to positive 1. I think now I got it from Taussig

Comment: @FahiFarjanaYusra The domain for the denominator  *is not* $[-1, 1]$. So, as I suspected, that was really the source of confusion.